# Sending Notifications from a SQL Server 2000 Job without SMTP Server on the Box

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, smtp, notifications, sql-server-agent

I have SQL Server 2000 installed on Windows 2003 Server.  We do not have SMTP installed on the box, so when creating a notification for a failed SQL Agent job, the email is not sent.

Is there a way to send out a notification without installing SMTP on the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [xp_sendmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx) of SQL 2000 you don't need SMTP on the box, you need a [MAPI Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175189.aspx). see: [How to configure a mail profile (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198233(SQL.80).aspx). In the MAPI profile used by SQL you can specify the prefered delivery options, eg. Exchange server conectivity, or the SMTP server used by the rest of your organization.

From [KB 263556 INF: How to Configure SQL Mail](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263556):

> SQL Server 2000 SQL Mail establishes
>   an extended MAPI connection with a
>   mail host, while SQLAgentMail
>   establishes a separate extended MAPI
>   connection. Both SQL Mail and
>   SQLAgentMail can connect with
>   Microsoft Exchange Server, or a Post
>   Office Protocol 3 (POP3) server.
>
> NOTE: Due to the limitation of only
>   providing extended MAPI support, SQL
>   Server 2000 requires a Microsoft
>   Outlook 2000 client (or later
>   version).
>
> Before you configure SQL Mail, you should test
>   the mail profile used by the mail
>   client to verify that you can use it
>   to send and receive e-mail to and from
>   the mail server.

Comment: Using MAPI profiles will make a mess of your server, cause hanging reboots that require you to travel to the server physcally, and not send mail at critical moments. From your other posts you're a very knowledgeable person, I can't believe you even suggest this.

Comment: @Andomar: The MAPI mess is the reason SQL 2005 deprecated the SQL Mail infrastructure (based on MAPI) and replaced it with SQL Database Mail infrastructure (based on SMTP). As the original post specifies SQL 2000, I have no choice but to point to the 'proper' configuration of SQL 2000. Unfortunately, that involves MAPI.

Comment: @Remus: No proper configuration involves MAPI, period.  MAPI guarantees a world of hurt.  I've downvoted your answer--  I hope you understand.

Comment: @Andomar: Sorry for the late response. If you have to use MAPI on SQL Server 2000 then so be it. I've had no problems with it (mostly :-): the main problem I've seen is not configuring the mailbox correctly for the SQL Server service account, *logged on* as the SQL Server service account. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party frewares (like BLAT) for the same purpose, or VB_Spripts (if you donot want ant 3rd party applications to be installed (http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm )